how to allow long Raw string literals to be compiled without separate resource files
I'm working on a C++ codebase which has been provided with some library's source files which I'm prevented from breaking some guidelines or changing the library logic and paradigms, for instance I'm not allowed to use resource files.
in the codebase source files there is a case which a very long raw string literal was used as following
constexpr auto kImGuiWS_js = R"(

    very long multiline string about 18000 characters

)";

and this causes some complications for example I get following error using MSVC compiler
Error   C2026    string too big, trailing characters truncated

which the documents indicate that

Before adjacent strings get concatenated, a string can't be longer
than 16380 single-byte characters.

also there is a neat non-invasive solution for allowing normal long string literal to be compiled without change in code logic
char sz[] =
"\
imagine a really, really "
"long string here\
";

but this doesn't seem to be a possibility for raw string literals, are there any workarounds that could keep this code structure and allow me prevent compiler errors about exceeded long string literal maximum length?

const char *foo = R"(abc)" R"(def)"; compiles on GCC and Clang. Not on MSVC, I take it?

The approach used by js2c is to use an array of char initializer. Which seems to have a higher limit. Source: one of the comments or this answer

@Botje: split that way also works with Msvc.

@Botje as your answer was correct and you mentioned it before everyone I will wait for your submission to accept it

No need. it's not a competition.


but this doesn't seem to be a possibility for raw string literals

It is:
const char *foo = R"(abc)" R"(def)";

https://godbolt.org/z/oEvcYfb9s
